# Entity Framework 5 and XElement fields

Tags: c#, xml, entity-framework, xelement, entity-framework-5

Started playing with Visual Studio 2012 RC and Entity Framework 5... absolutely loving it but wondering if there's a *cleaner* way to do this.

I would like to cut out the middle-man of parsing the XML every time, and setting it via .ToString()

```
public class MyEFEntity
{
    [NotMapped()]
    public XElement Tags { 
        get { return XElement.Parse(tags); } 
        set { tags = value.ToString(); } }

    [Column("Tags", TypeName = "xml"), Required]
    public string tags { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In principle there is no better way. You need two properties - one for `XElement` and one for backing persisted string. If you want to reduce amount of parsing and conversion you need to implement some infrastructure for that. General approach would be:

- Handle `ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized` event - if the materialized object is `MyEFEntity` parse string and save it to `XElement` property. If you are using `DbContext` you can still get `ObjectContext` through its explicitly implemented `IObjectContextAdapter`.
- Override `SaveChanges` - in the method find all modified or inserted instances of `MyEFEntity` through `DbContext.ChangeTracker.GetEntries` and save their XML to string property

Comment: Thanks, this works.  I was just hoping there was a more elegant way of doing it.  I may investigate a way of doing this more cleanly using attributes and a custom `DbContext`.  If only MS would open-source EF. :)